# Create a regular expression using input

Tags: regex, python-3.x, input

Write a function that takes a string and does the same thing as the strip()
string method. If no other arguments are passed other than the string to
strip, then whitespace characters will be removed from the beginning and
end of the string. Otherwise, the characters specified in the second argument
to the function will be removed from the string. (Using regular expressions)

I made it so it removes the pattern of letters or symbols, not the class of symbols:

```
import re

def stripas(tekstas, argum):
    tekstas = argum.sub('', tekstas)
    print(tekstas)

print('Input the text:')
tekstas = input()

print('Input the text (Optional):')
argumentas = input()

if argumentas == '':
    argum = re.compile('\s')
else:
    argum = re.compile(argumentas)

stripas(tekstas, argum)
```

Result using *""* as argument (Whitespaces removed):

```
Input the text:
 hello
Input the text (Optional):

hello
>>>
```

Result using *"el"* as argument (only pattern removed, one *l* remained):

```
Input the text:
 hello
Input the text (Optional):
el
 hlo
>>>
```

My question finaly: **Is it possible to create class just like "r'[*INPUT*]" without getting an error?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this,

```
if argumentas == '':
    argum = re.compile(r'^\s+|\s+$')       # default: remove leading(or trailing) spaces
else:
    argum = re.compile(r'{}'.format(argumentas))  # for custom removing by input
```

If you want `default stripping` + `custom input removing`,

```
argum = re.compile(r'^\s+|\s+$|{}'.format(argumentas))    # default stripping + input characters removing
```

Output is,

```
Input the text:
   hello every one
Input the text (Optional):
lo|[en]        # user input regex
   hl vry o    # custom removing by input
hl vry o       # default stripping + custom removing by input
-------------
l+|v.*?e        # lazy mode and quantifier, +,*, etc..
heo ery one
---------------------
(?<=h)e|(?:(?!eve).)+(?= one)   # lookaround
hllo e one
```

Comment: I just paused Breaking Bad for this. 
Hm interesting, the 1st part with space remove its logical your way, because running program my way cuts all the spaces, even between word, using ^ and $ works wonders.
However 2nd change works same even if i just put:
*else:*
    *argum = re.compile(argumentas)*
and just input the expression. {}.format I am not yet familiar with this syntax :)

Comment: I wondered how can I put stuff int between (r'*stuff*'). Thank you!

Comment: What's up? any problem? If the input string has multiple lines, then use `multiline flag`, `(?m)`, then above whitespaces stripping regex will be changed to `r'(?m)^\s+|\s+$'`

Comment: if i had multi-line text i could add one more argument. It is possible to add a lot of arguments like re.DOTALL. example:
*someRegexValue = re.compile('foo', re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL | re.VERBOSE)*

Comment: OK, that's it:-)